# Using a parameter shared by a normal distribution and a separate multinormal distribution

Tags: stan

### Question

I have two measurements, one is a scalar measurement `x` and the other is two-element vector `(y,z)`. The sampling distribution of the former is a normal distribution, and the sampling distribution of the latter is a multinormal distribution. The location parameter for `x` and for `y` are assumed to be the same, `mu_1`. In other words, both `x` and `y` provide information about the common parameter `mu_1`.

Here is my model:

[image: normal-and-multinormal]

```
\begin{aligned} 
x \sim Normal(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2) \\
(y,z) \sim MultiNormal((\mu_1, \mu_2), \Sigma)
\end{aligned}
```

How can I specify this in Stan so that the parameter `mu_1` is used in both sampling distributions, and I can thus get a posterior distribution for `mu_1`?

My confusion here stems from the fact that `mu_1` is a scalar parameter in the first distribution, but part of a parameter vector in the second distribution. Also, I used a normal distribution and multinormal distribution as examples just for simplicity, but I'm looking for a solution that will work for other combinations of sampling distributions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a transformed parameters block, where the vector parameter `mu_1_2 = (mu_1, mu_2)` is created using previously-defined scalar parameters `mu_1` and `mu_2`.

Here's a basic example:

```
data {
  real x;
  vector[2] y_z;
  real<lower=0> sigma_x;
  matrix[2,2] sigma_y_z;
}

parameters {
    real mu_1;
    real mu_2;
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[2] mu_1_2;
  mu_1_2[1] = mu_1; 
  mu_1_2[2] = mu_2;
}

model {
  x ~ normal(mu_1, sigma_x)
  y_z ~ multi_normal(mu_1_2, sigma_y_z)
}
```